# JQuery Editable Select with Data From Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, http-post

Any one could help on this case, I have a select tag in which the data is loading from the SQL database using Ajax POST method.

My code is below but it's not working correctly but not displaying any errors also. I am using  editable select for achieving this. Any helps will be appreciated.

LINKS

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" />
        <script src="https://rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>
```

AJAX

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        // url: "SerialNumberCapture.aspx/GetAllCompanyDetails",
        url: "ViewSerialNumbers.aspx/ViewGetAllTransactionID",
        data: "{CompanyCode:'" + companycode + "',TransactionType:'" + transype + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //$('#ddlViewTransactionType option:not(:first)').remove();

            $("#ddltransactionId").empty().append("<option value='0'>Select</option>");
            //$("#ddltransactionId").empty();
            $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {

                $("#ddltransactionId").append($("<option></option>").val(value.TransId).html(value.TransId));

            });
            $('#ddltransactionId').editableSelect();

          },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Failed: " + result.status + ": " + result.responseText);
        }
       });
```

Comment: Are you sure that the success callback is called ?

Comment: Yes, if this line is commented  $('#ddltransactionId').editableSelect(); then it works perfectly .

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused by the line `<b>  $('#ddltransactionId').editableSelect();</b>` You cannot write to an html tag this way in JavaScript. Here you should just call `$('#ddltransactionId').editableSelect();` instead.

Comment: Removed but still the same

Answer (score 0):

For those who may had face this issue, I am posting a workaround that i have done to fix this issue. It support only in HTML5

```
                    <input type="text" list="ddltransactionId" id="txtTransactionId" />
                    <datalist id="ddltransactionId">
                        <option value="0">Select</option>
                    </datalist>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem here is how you have to do it

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:34168/api/machine/getall", function (data) {
  $("#modal_machine_name_select").html('');
  $.each(data, function () {
    console.log(data);
    var dt = this;
    
    $('#modal_machine_name_select').editableSelect('add', function () {
      $(this).attr('value', dt.Machine_id);
      $(this).text(dt.Machine_Name);
    });
```

check the documentation in here => https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select